# Android chrome multi select drop down issue and by default a value is selected

Tags: android, html, google-chrome

I have a multi select dropdown in my website which shows as a text box, but same thing is shown as a single select drop down in android tablet in chrome browser and by default top value selected, I want no value selected in android chrome also, any help ?

The below code is after Ajax function call.

```
success: function(jsonstring){
    vx='';          
    var json = JSON.parse(jsonstring);

    if (json != '') {                   
        $.each(json, function(index, element) {
           if(index==0)
                vx+='<option value="'+element.ID+'" selected>'+element.NAME+'</option>';
           else
                vx+='<option value="'+element.ID+'">'+element.NAME+'</option>';
        });
    } else {
         vx='<option value="" selected>No Matching Record Found</option>';                  
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Edit your question and add code instead of putting bunch of not formatted text to comment.

Comment: Just click `edit` that is located below your question (not comment with code). Than add single blank line, press four times "space" and start typing your code. Every code line must be indented by 4*spaces. http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: thank you, I formatted code now